# What is last_num refers to in the array sort function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

When we sort an array we write our function like the following, what does the last_nom mean here?

```
objs.sort(function(a, b){
return a.last_nom == b.last_nom ? 0 : +(a.last_nom > b.last_nom) || -1;
});
```

Trying to understand the concept behind but failed to find useful explanation. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Belongs on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: last_mon is probably a key (from a key/pair object).
Something like: a = { last_nom: "benseler", first_nom: "christian" }. Take a lok at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript

Comment: It's for [sorting an `Array` of `Object`s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript). `last_nom` would be a property of each object.

Comment: what is the last_num properties though? do the array/objects have this property when they are created?

Comment: @BRAYBRAY Yes. The objects in the array should already have a `last_nom` property for this `.sort()` to use them. An example is given in the text of the question I linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code expects `a` and `b` to have a property called `last_nom`